# Can one element accept sortable droppables on behalf of another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have two connected sortable lists, but each one is in a larger block element.  Something like:

```
<div class="items_box">
    <ul class="items">
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="items_box">
    <ul class="items">
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

With this Javascript:

```
$(".items").sortable({connectWith: [".items"]});
```

The `.items_box` divs are taller then the lists.  I'd like to make the entirety of each div accept items on behalf of its list.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to make the **container** the sortable, and change the **.items** property to look for your items within the list.

```
$('.items_box').sortable({ 
  connectWith: '.items_box', 
  items: '> .items > li' 
});
```

I have posted a [working example](http://jsbin.com/oyeyi/edit) for you (although there are issues with dragging into an empty list, but that's a new problem ;)

Note also that **connectWith** no longer allows arrays of selectors. Seperate them with commas instead.